# Android stop a thread that is executing a single library function

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an application which uses a separate thread to execute a calculation performed in code from a separate library. I would like the user to able to cancel this operation as, depending on the parameters, it can take a long time.

I cannot use a stopping variable or check for interrupts as the calculation from the applications point of view is a single line

```
public void run() {
    result = library.performCalculation(params);
}
```

I would like to be able to use `thread.stop()` but as far as I'm aware this is not posible on android.

Is there anyway I can cause the thread to stop running?

Comment: Thread.stop() is longer the part of java. It´s has been Deprecated, therefore you can´t use that method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, `Thread.stop()` is not available on Android (and even on systems where it is still supported, its problems outweight its usefulness).

What you can do is two-fold. First, call `thread.interrupt()` to set an interrupted flag on the thread running your library. Second, modify your library at appropriate point(s) to call `isInterrupted()` to determine if it is interrupted and, if so, it should voluntarily clean up and leave.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to modify the library, it wasn't exactly built with this in mind. In the places that I have implemented the `isInterrupted()` check though it's working well.

Answer (score 0):

An AsyncTask can be Cancelled.  Put that into an AsyncTask and call

```
 AsyncTask.cancel(true);
```

Comment: Like the `thread.interrupt()` call in my answer, `AsyncTask.cancel()` does not stop the thread, it only sets a flag. The thread must still check the flag and decide what to do if its `doInBackground()` method is still busy.